# Error -2147467259 in Visual Basic 6.0 while sending XML to Web Service

Tags: web-services, vb6, payment-gateway, system-error

I am using Web Service for Payment Gateway. I have written below code. It is working in Windows XP Operating System.

But when I am running this application in "Windows Embedded System (Operating System)", it is showing as "System Error -2147467259".

I am unable to trace the error. Please help me.

Here is the code:
    Dim vXML
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    vXML = BuildXML()
    vXML = SoapWrapper(vXML)

```
httpReq.open &quot;POST&quot;, webServiceUrl, False
httpReq.setRequestHeader &quot;Content-Type&quot;, &quot;text/xml&quot;
httpReq.setRequestHeader &quot;Connection&quot;, &quot;close&quot;
httpReq.setRequestHeader &quot;SOAPAction&quot;, transactionUrl
httpReq.send vXML
```

I am getting error in line "httpReq.send vXML".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
httpReq.send pvToByteArray(vXML)
...

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

You might somehow have "special" characters in the XML string.